# Create BoundingBoxes on a Model

Tags: xna, monogame, bounding-boxes

I am trying to create multiple `BoundingBoxes` on a `Model` by following this tutorial:

https://electronicmeteor.wordpress.com/2011/10/25/bounding-boxes-for-your-model-meshes/

However, I keep getting this error: `Requested range extends past the end of the array.` on this line:

```
part.VertexBuffer.GetData(part.VertexOffset * stride, vertexData, 0, part.NumVertices, stride);
```

I can't figure out why it is giving me that. I load my model and try to create the boxes like this:

```
Model model = this.Content.Load<Model>("Cube");
MeshModel box = new MeshModel(model);
```

Instead of passing a `String` path of the model, I just pass the `Model` itself (I changed the constructor to accept `Model model`).

Any help would be appreciated!

Here's what the debugger says (the `vertexStride` and `VertexBuffer` has `24` which is the same size as the `vertexData` so it should be ok):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the tutorial you are using, `vertexData` is an array of a number of  `VertexPositionNormalTexture`. But if your cube is made from a type of Vertex that is different (say `VertexPositionColor` for instance), then you have to adjust `vertexData` accordingly.

`VertexPositionColor[] vertexData = new VertexPositionColor[part.NumVertices];`

If you expand the Vertex Declaration line on your debugger output, we can see what type of Vertex Blender gave you and Xna probably has a Vertex that fits it.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` message. If you're using [XNA's `GetData` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197082.aspx), that can occur because:

- The vertex stride is larger than the vertex buffer, or
- The vertex stride is too small for the type of data requested.

It seems likely that you're `vertexData` array is too small to hold the requested amount of data, but you should attach a debugger and verify. It's also possible the calculations you're doing for the other parameters do not match the actual data you have available in the buffer.

Comment: I attached the debugger output in the OP. The size seems fine, unless I'm misunderstanding. My model is the default cube from Blender (when you first open it). If I make the `vertexData` array bigger then it just fills it with `0` values for the `VertexPositionNormalTexture` after the 24th index.